# why std::is_constructible will return false if reference type is not match?

Tags: c++, templates, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm currently studying some template stuffs. But I got a question.
I have a class like this

```cpp
class myobj{
    public:
    int val;
    char single;
    string name;
    myobj(){}
    myobj(int a):val(a){};
    myobj(int a, char b, string& c): val(a), single(b), name(move(c)){};

};
```

And here is the `main` function

```cpp
int main(){
    cout << is_constructible<myobj, int>::value << endl; //true
    cout << is_constructible<myobj, int, char, string>::value << endl; //false
    cout << is_constructible<myobj, int, char, string&>::value << endl; //true
    return 0;
}
```

I can not understand why the second will be false. Is that mean I can not use a `string` to construct the object?
When the function signature shows the parameter is pass-by-reference, I think it is OK to pass an value to it. Is there any misunderstanding about the reference?

Comment: Did you try using a `const` reference?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel in these cases i normally would do by value, then the user of the interface can choose and it works for rvalue, and lvalue types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try it:

```
myobj(1, 'c', std::string{"lalala"});
```

This is a string yeah, so it should compile? No:

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::string&' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&'} to an rvalue of type 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'}
   20 |     myobj(1, 'c', std::string{"lalala"});
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1474483d1f5c1091)

`string` in this context can refer to an rvalue, but an rvalue cannot be referenced by a normal lvalue reference. A `string&` must be mutable, so there is a difference (a very strong one) between `string` and `string&`.